# How can I SET NAMES latin1 to work in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, excel, database, vb.net

I'm not able to successfully convert my data to "latin1" in my VB.net app. And either show the correct data in a gridview or what I am trying to export the correct data to excel.
Every German word like: "Köln" or "möglich" are shown like: "KÃ¶ln" and "mÃ¶glich".
My Database is a mysql database and the tables are latin1 format, I cannot change that.

On my MySQL Workbench if I, before the start of my SELECT statement, do the "SET NAMES latin1;" everything is shown perfectly, but when I do that in my app the data are shown with the wrong character.
I have set my connection string to "latin1" and I have tried utf8, utf-8 and utf8mb4 and none of them works.
server=000.000.000.000;userid=admin;password=admin;database=center;CharacterSet=latin1;

here is a code that reads the data in an gridview:

```
 Private Sub TabelleAnzeigen_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadTable_btn.Click
    CheckBoxAnrDetail.Checked = False
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New Data.DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    Dim mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "SET NAMES latin1;
                 SELECT ccce.callerid,
                        ccce.datetime_entry_queue,
                        ccce.duration_wait,
                        ccce.status,
                        ce.name,
                        ccce.uniqueid
                FROM
                        center.call_entry ccce,
                        campaign_entry ce
                WHERE
                        ccce.datetime_entry_queue BETWEEN ' " & DateTimePicker1Centrale.Text & " ' AND ' " & DateTimePicker2Centrale.Text & " '
                        AND ccce.status = 'abandonada'
                        AND ccce.id_campaign = ce.id 
                ORDER BY
                        ce.name,
                        ccce.datetime_entry_queue;"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = command
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridViewCentrale.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
        mysqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        LabelAnrufNRCentrale.Text = DataGridViewCentrale.RowCount - 1
        mysqlconn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: VB net and c# use utf16 , so convert your latin1/asccii into utf 16.

Comment: Unfortunatley not working for me, if I cahange the Connectionstring to: "uft16" or "utf 16" and if I change it in my sql query i got the error: "Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value od 'utf16'"

Comment: try Select CONVERT(CAST(`name`as BINARY) USING utf8) From Table1; like here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91b3aa/4

Comment: Perfect, thx a loooooot